# android studio 3 sdk missing at installation

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio-3.0

I recently re-install my windows. ( Windows 10 64-bit)

I installed JDK 9 propperly. Now i'm trying to install android studio 3 but Android SDK is missing from installation. When i open the program, Setup Wizard appears and gets stucked on Downloading Components with this item: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip and downloads it over and over again.

Thanks.

Comment: It's very difficult to help with this kind of issue.  It might help if you provide a screenshot, but for the most part, all I can say is try uninstalling and reinstalling android studio.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android SDK is missing]
Indeed, I have downloaded the latest version, and the "Android SDK" is missing.